# AngularJS change server url with input text

Tags: angularjs, cordova, url, file-upload, upload

I want to send a zip file to a server with angularjs and cordova file transfer.

The server url must be variable.

**.js-File**

```
// initial value
$scope.serverurl = "http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/some/text/storeData"; 

    function getServerURL() {
        $http.get($scope.serverurl)
            .then(function (res) {
                $scope.serverurl = res.data;
                $log.info("res.data" + res.data);
            });
    }

    $scope.change = function() {
        getServerURL();
    };


// file upload
$cordovaFileTransfer.upload($scope.serverurl, targetPath, options)
```

**.html-File**

```
  <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
    <span class="input-label">Server-URL</span>
      <input type="text" ng-bind="serverurl" ng-model="serverurl" ng-change="change()" placeholder="{{serverurl}}" />
      {{serverurl}}
  </label>
```

The initial value is always used to send the file to the server.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: i want to change the server url by type something in the input field

Comment: So what happens now? Can you remove the ng-bind="serverurl" and try again?

Comment: I've already tried it. The value "http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/some/text/storeData" is always used by the upload function.

Comment: $scope.server = {
            url : "http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/some/text/storeData"
        }; and ng-model="server.url" solves the problem!